# Outlook: Invalid signature of mixed HTML/Plaintext E-Mails

Tags: outlook, html, text, digital-signatures

while testing new security GPOs, i've found the problem that with E-Mails that contain HTML and Plaintext, Outlook always complains about invalid signatures or tempered messages, even though with the same E-Mails as pure HTML or pure Plaintext, Outlook has no problem with the signature. Can i fix this, or is this a Outlook bug?

This doesn't seem to be a problem with forced conversion, and i cant force use of HTML or Plaintext.

Comment: Define "invalid signatures".

Comment: With invalid signatures, i mean that Outlook complains that the signature is invalid or that the message has been tempered with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is your email server? Exchange server?

Does this issue occur to OWA If you use exchange accounts?

In addition, I want to confirm if this issue only occur to the outlook clients applied GPO?

Comment: We have an exchange server, it happens to all clients.

Comment: Could you disable the GPO and check if this issue continues?

Comment: It does continue